# internal linked hashmap error while running flutter project

Tags: flutter

I am having this error in my code.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>'
```

Here's my code:

```
Future<List> getmatches() async{
 String url="https://cricapi.com/api/cricketScore?apikey=oJmzPtpZJXcIQmxAjOlP5Zss1At1&unique_id=1034809";
  http.Response response=await http.get(url);
  return jsonDecode(response.body);
```

And here is the error:

```
 Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a 
 subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the function's return type to `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>` so it'll look like

```dart
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getmatches() async {
 String url="https://cricapi.com/api/cricketScore?apikey=oJmzPtpZJXcIQmxAjOlP5Zss1At1&unique_id=1034809";
  http.Response response=await http.get(url);
  return jsonDecode(response.body);
}
```